# Non-asymptotic upper bound of right tail of Gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, special-functions

I'm wondering if there is any non-asymptotic upper bound for the following Gamma function:
$$f_a(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}t^a\exp(-t)dt$$
for $x>0,a>0$? Something like $x^a\exp(-x)$?

Comment: In what sense are you looking for a "non-asymptotic" upper bound? Obviously $\Gamma(1+a)$ is an upper bound for all $x$, and $f_a(x)$ is not asymptotic to $\Gamma(1+a)$ (except as $x \to 0$) but that is clearly not what you are after.  Are you looking for tight upper bounds, or for big-theta behavior, or what?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the unclear statement. I'm looking for some tight non asymptotic upper bound. The bound should be tight for both $x\to0$ and $x\to\infty$. The tightness is not that stringent. For example, I treat $C_1(C_2x)^n$ as a tight upper bound for $x^n$ as long as $C_1,C_2$ are absolute constants independent of $x$ and $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Gabcke thesis, that you can download at 
http://hdl.handle.net/11858/00-1735-0000-0022-6013-8
page 84 you can find

Theorem: The incomplete gamma function 
$$\Gamma(a,x)=\int_x^\infty e^{-v}v^{a-1}\,dv,\qquad   \text{$x>0$ and $a$ real numbers}$$
satisfies  for $a\ge 1$ and $x>a$
$$\Gamma(a,x)\le a e^{-x} x^{a-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you! That's not in English, which I guess is the reason I cannot find the result.

Comment: I think that Gabcke has translated his thesis to English. But I do not find now a link.  I have also a translation to Spanish.

Comment: There is a problem with this answer for smallish $x$. For instance, at $a = 3$ and $x = 1.5$, we have $$3 e^{-1.5} (1.5)^2 < 1.5062 < 1.6176 < \Gamma(3,1.5)$$ You wanted an upper bound that works everywhere; this one does not.

Comment: @Mark Fischler  The hypothesis of the theorem says  x > a.   Your values do not satisfy this condition.

Comment: Yes, but the problem posed does not stipulate that $x > a$, it asks for an upper bound good for all $x,a>0$.

Comment: So is there some similar bound for $x<a$?

Comment: @neverevernever Since $\lim_{x\to0} \Gamma(a,x)=\Gamma(a)$. A good bound for $x<a$ is $\Gamma(a,x)\le \Gamma(a)$. Perhaps this can be improved, but only slightly when $x$ is near $0$.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the OP, the result by Gabcke cited in the answer by user juan is as follows: 
\begin{equation*}
 f_a(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}t^a e^{-t}\,dt=\Gamma(a+1,x)\le(a+1) x^a e^{-x}=:B_1(a,x) 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\text{for $a>0$ and $x\ge a+1$.} 
\end{equation*}

One can obtain the following improvement of this result: 
\begin{equation*}
 f_a(x)=\Gamma(a+1,x)\le x^a e^{-x}\,\frac1{1-a/x}=:B_2(a,x) \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\text{for $a>0$ and $x>a$. } \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
Indeed, for $a>0$ and $x>a+1$ we have $B_2(a,x)<B_1(a,x)$.

Moreover, by l'Hospital's rule, for each real $a>0$ 
\begin{equation*}
B_2(a,x)\sim f_a(x), \quad B_1(a,x)\sim (a+1)f_a(x) 
\end{equation*}
as $x\to\infty$. So, the bound $B_2(a,x)$ is asymptotically optimal as $x\to\infty$, whereas the bound $B_2(a,x)$ is not.

---

Let us now prove the claim (1) under condition (2). For $t>x[>a>0]$, let $g(t):=a\ln t-t$. Since the function $g$ is concave, we have 
\begin{equation*}
 g(t)\le g_x(t):=g(x)+g'(x)(t-x)=a\ln x-x+(a/x-1)(t-x). 
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
 f_a(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{g(t)}\,dt
 \le \int_{x}^{\infty}e^{g_x(t)}\,dt =B_1(a,x), 
\end{equation*}
as claimed.